# How to delete object if it is out of PolygonCollider2D borders in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have PolygonCollider2D, on its perimetr i spawn objects which moves to the center, how can i delete these objects when they are out of borders' perimetr? I tryed to use
if (!wholeBorderCollider.bounds.Contains(transform.position)) in object's script but it doesn't work.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MeteoriteMoverDeleter : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float _speed = 6f;
[SerializeField] private float _directionDeviation = 4f;

private Rigidbody2D _rb;

public PolygonCollider2D wholeBorderCollider;
private void Start()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    _rb.velocity = (-RandomDirection(transform).normalized * _speed);
}

private void Update()
{
    if (!wholeBorderCollider.bounds.Contains(transform.position))
        Destroy(this);
}

private Vector2 RandomDirection(Transform transform)
{
    float directionMultiplier = Random.Range(10 - _directionDeviation, 10 + _directionDeviation);
    int coordinateToMultiply = Random.Range(0, 2);
    if (coordinateToMultiply == 1)
        return new Vector2(transform.position.x * directionMultiplier, transform.position.y);
    else
        return new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y * directionMultiplier);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Destroy the `gameObject`, not `this`.  `this` refers to the component, not the entire object.

Comment: Oh, it was so easy, thanks, solved the problem.